# Trying to fetch API via axios, but don't know how to access

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, axios, fetch-api

I try to fetch some data from an API. The API is formatted like this:

```json
[
  {
    "1": {
      "appid": 1,
      "name": "bmw"
    },
    "2": {
      "appid": 2,
      "name": "mercedes"
    },
    "3": {
      "appid": 3,
      "name": "tesla"
    }
  }
]
```

And in react my app.js looks like this:

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import ItemsGrid from "./components/items/ItemsGrid";

function App() {
  const [items, setItems] = useState([]);
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchItems = async () => {
      const result = await axios({
        url: "http://localhost:3013/items",
        method: "get",
        timeout: 8000,
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
      });

      console.log(result.data);
      setItems(result.data);
      setIsLoading(false);
    };

    fetchItems();
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <ItemsGrid isLoading={isLoading} items={items} />
      <h1>Hello</h1>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

And the ItemsGrid:

```js
import React from "react";

const ItemsGrid = ({ items, isLoading }) => {
  return isLoading ? (
    <h1>Loading...</h1>
  ) : (
    <div>
      {items.map((item) => (
        <h1 key={item.appid}>{item.name}</h1>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};

export default ItemsGrid;
```

So nothing is to see beacause I don't know how to access the array. In the console log I see there is something:

```
[{…}]
0: {1: {…}, 2: {…}, 3: {…}}
length: 1
__proto__: Array(0)
```

Anyone know how to show the names via mapping?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to turn the array with an object into a regular array you can use [Object.values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values) on the first element of the array:

```js
useEffect(() => {
  const fetchItems = async () => {
    const result = await axios({
      url: "http://localhost:3013/items",
      method: "get",
      timeout: 8000,
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
    });

    setItems(Object.values(result.data[0]));
    setIsLoading(false);
  };

  fetchItems();
}, []);
```

Answer (score 1):

When you set items, you can use `Object#values` function to get all values of the first element your returning data.

```js
const fetchItems = async () => {
  ...
  setItems(Object.values(result.data[0]));
  ...
};
```